# Delete Unique permission in one library in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions, sp-online, unique-permissions

I have a problem with my Sharepoint. I migrated data from NAS to SPO using a migrate tool. This solution adds unique permission to the library and sublibraries. I have more than 250k objects so I can't use web site to delete this, I tried to use this method [Remove unique permissions on all locations on site SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184492/remove-unique-permissions-on-all-locations-on-site-sharepoint-2013)

I Changed the start function from Get-SPWeb to Get-SPOService.

this does not work. Could you help me, how can I delete unique permission in one library on one site in Sharepoint online when is it more than 5000 objects?

Comment: Hello Jarkacz, Could you please provide a resource for the migration tool that you used from NAS to SPO? I look forward to your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below powershell script:

```
$ListName = "Documents"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://yoursite
#Get all list items in batches
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500
#Iterate through each list item
ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{
    #Check if the Item has unique permissions
    $HasUniquePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $ListItem -Property "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
    If($HasUniquePermissions)
    {       
      Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $ListName -Identity $ListItem.ID -InheritPermissions

    }
}
```

Reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/powershell-to-delete-unique-permissions-for-all-list-items-sharepoint-online.html

Comment: i have message:
Get-PnPContext : The term 'Get-PnPContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operabl
e program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

i changed connect-pnponline to connect sposervice because i have SPonline

Comment: You need to use Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline to intall pnp powershell:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: thanks a lot! i have ~275k items but i see this is work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below PowerShell script:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Function to remove unique permissions and inherit from the parent
Function Remove-ListUniquePermissions
{
param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ListName
    )

    Try {
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

        #sharepoint online powershell inherit permissions
        $List=$Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
        $List.ResetRoleInheritance()
        $List.Update()
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        Write-Host "Unique Permissions are removed and inherited from the Parent!" -ForegroundColor Green
    }

    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Deleting Unique Permissions!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
#sharepoint online powershell reset permissions
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com"
$ListName="Projects"

#Call the function to remove unique permissions from a list
Remove-ListUniquePermissions -SiteURL $SiteURL -ListName $ListName
```

Note:

For more than 5000 items condition, you need to load the items with a row limit 5000 - if the result gives more than 5k then need to call the above function  **Remove-ListUniquePermission**

**Example of how to call the above function Remove-ListUniquePermission**

```
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
## View XML
$camlQuery= @"
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Query>
        <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">5000</RowLimit>
</View>
"@

$currentCollection = $list.GetItems($camlQuery)
$ctx.Load($currentCollection)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

if ($currentCollection -eq 5000)
{
   Remove-ListUniquePermissions -SiteURL $SiteURL -ListName $ListName

}
```

Source:

[Delete Unique Permissions on a List or Library in SharePoint Online using PowerShell:](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/01/sharepoint-online-delete-unique-permissions-using-powershell.html)

[Get All Items in 5000+ large list with CSOM in PowerShell](https://www.sptrenches.com/2016/06/get-all-items-in-5000-large-list-with.html)

Comment: "$ListName="Projects" what if i don't have any list? i want use script only to library

Comment: You can pass as $ListName="YourLibraryName"

Comment: thx, but i checked, and this is not delete unique permission in subfolders but only only in the library I pointed out

Comment: sorry for stupuid question but i must change $DocLibName and $list? i try to reset permission for 
#sharepoint online powershell reset permissions
$SiteURL="https://silfraconsulting.sharepoint.com/sites/Public"
$ListName="Dokumenty"